# Import datas from a magento store to another

Tags: magento, import

Actually, the company where i'm working has two magento stores on two different installations.
But is this possible to import orders, customers, attributes, products of a magento to another ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're importing it can be achieved in several ways.

Importing products, stock levels and customers can be done via the Magento admin > system > import/export > data profiles using .csv file, watch out this can be annoyingly slow so I wouldn't recommend this for anything more then 5,000 products.

Importing anything else can be done programmatically or via extensions free and or premium. I've personally used extensions from [Commerce Extensions](http://www.commerceextensions.com) which work really well for importing products, categories, attributes, orders and much more with decent speed. Importing 5,000 products with images on a 1GB of RAM server took around 40mins.

Aside to that you could look into [Magmi](http://wiki.magmi.org) which is great for large data sets as the speeds will save you hours on import. Hope that helps!

Cheers, Sas

Comment: As there aren't too much datas (800 products), I think I'm going to proceed step by step. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Better to do this using database.
With a SQL query results are better.
Dataflow creates some bugs.

THX